# How to delete a item with a .filter method in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am building an [Expense tracker](https://codesandbox.io/s/expense-tracker-7dyor) and I need to add functionality to delete the items that I add. I am trying to use .filter method to see if the expense id state variable matches up with the parameter. Then I need to pass the function into props

```
` const [expense, setExpense] = useState([]);
  const [expenseName, setExpenseName] = useState("");
  const [expenseAmt, setExpenseAmt] = useState();
.
.


 const removeHandler = id => {
    let expenses = expense.filter(e => {
      return e.id !== id;
    });
    setExpense({ expenses });
  };

.
.
 {expense.map((expense, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index} expense={expense} remove={removeHandler} />
      ))}


`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an error on the `setExpense` call. You should be calling it with the raw value (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state), but you're calling it with an object with the key of 'expenses' whose value is `expenses`.

Try this for your `removeHandler`:

```
const removeHandler = id => e => {
    const filteredExpense = expense.filter(e => {
      return e.id !== id;
    });

    setExpense(filteredExpense);
};
```

By the way, you should use the id as the key in your render component, and call the removeHandler like so to actually create a bound function tied to each expense.id:

`<ListItem key={expense.id} expense={expense} remove={removeHandler(expense.id)} />`

Comment: I implemented the code, but it is giving me an error saying my expense.reduce function is not a function which didn't happen before

Comment: Your code had multiple errors:

1st: `setExpense({ filterExpense });` <-- you still put braces around it. It should be: `setExpense(filterExpense);`

2nd: Remove function should be a function that takes an event so it should look more like this: `const removeHandler = id => e => { ... }`

3rd: `<button className="remove-button">{remove}Remove</button>` <-- you're calling remove immediately. It should  be: `<button className="remove-button" onClick={remove}>Remove</button>`

Check this fork out: https://codesandbox.io/s/expense-tracker-ql2rj